# How does MAML inner loop optimization works?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, gradient, meta-learning, model-agnostic-meta-learning

I started to learn meta-learning, reading the MAML paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.03400.pdf

[image]

In the inner loop, I am calculating adapted parameters for each task, I will be doing multiple steps of inner SGD.
I will calculate adapted parameters after two or more gradient steps ($\theta{'}$, $\theta^{''}$ , $\theta^{n}$), then using testing parameters, I will have a loss in respect to the original $\theta$ (If I understand the derivation correctly). Now I am supposed to backpropagate through the gradient. Unfortunately, I am not sure how it is done...

> *Model-Agnostic Meta-Learning for Fast Adaptation of Deep Networks
> Page 3.*
>
>  "The MAML meta-gradient update involves a gradient
> through a gradient"

To do this, I understand that I have to store each $\theta^{n}$, but don't know how the loss from $\theta^{n}$ to $\theta^{n-1}$ is transferred up to the original  $\theta$.
I guess that the for the last series of parameters ($\theta^{n}$) loss is calculated in the standard way with the testing set, but then I somehow need to pass information saying how much the previous set of parameters was wrong... *(Gradient of the gradient?)*

I see Hessian and vector products popping up everywhere on the internet, but I cannot imagine how that works, and have no idea how it is calculated and passed/implemented...

Can someone explain to me how the inner loop [back-propagation trough meta-gradient] is working - how the derivations go and how loss is transferred/updated?

Comment: I see too many questions in this post. Edit your post to leave only one specific question.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, I have clarified the question, and I hope that it is now more readable.

Answer (score 0):

According to: "[Model-Agnostic Meta-Learning for Fast Adaptation of Deep Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03400)" it is initialized in [Class MAML](https://github.com/cbfinn/maml/blob/a7f45f1bcd7457fe97b227a21e89b8a82cc5fa49/maml.py#L17):

```
class MAML:
    def __init__(self, dim_input=1, dim_output=1, test_num_updates=5):
        """ must call construct_model() after initializing MAML! """
        self.dim_input = dim_input
        self.dim_output = dim_output
        self.update_lr = FLAGS.update_lr
        self.meta_lr = tf.placeholder_with_default(FLAGS.meta_lr, ())
        self.classification = False
        self.test_num_updates = test_num_updates
        if FLAGS.datasource == 'sinusoid':
            self.dim_hidden = [40, 40]
            self.loss_func = mse
            self.forward = self.forward_fc
            self.construct_weights = self.construct_fc_weights
        elif FLAGS.datasource == 'omniglot' or FLAGS.datasource == 'miniimagenet':
            self.loss_func = xent
            self.classification = True
            if FLAGS.conv:
                self.dim_hidden = FLAGS.num_filters
                self.forward = self.forward_conv
                self.construct_weights = self.construct_conv_weights
            else:
                self.dim_hidden = [256, 128, 64, 64]
                self.forward=self.forward_fc
                self.construct_weights = self.construct_fc_weights
            if FLAGS.datasource == 'miniimagenet':
                self.channels = 3
            else:
                self.channels = 1
            self.img_size = int(np.sqrt(self.dim_input/self.channels))
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unrecognized data source.')
```

> "How does MAML inner loop optimization work?"

Where Rectified Linear Unit (ReLU) neural networks are locally almost linear ([Goodfellow et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6572),
2015), and second derivatives close
to zero, using a first-order approximation removes the need for computing Hessian-vector products in an additional backward pass.

It is initialized by xavier_initializer_conv2d from TensorFlow, as explained in "[Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Understanding-the-difficulty-of-training-deep-Glorot-Bengio/b71ac1e9fb49420d13e084ac67254a0bbd40f83f)", Xavier Glorot and Yoshua Bengio, Proceedings of the Thirteenth International Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics, PMLR 9:249-256, 2010.

A method to alleviate the risk of overfitting for gradient-based meta-learning is explained in: "[Regularizing Meta-Learning via Gradient Dropout](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.05859)" - April 13 2020, by Tseng, Chen, Tsai, Liu, Lin, and Yang:

> "[they] aim to find model parameters that
> are sensitive to changes in the task, such that small changes
> in the parameters will produce large improvements on the
> loss function of any task drawn from $p(T)$, when altered in
> the direction of the gradient of that loss.".

Combined, those methods shorten the time taken to complete each pass.

In the line:

```
FLAGS.datasource == 'omniglot' or FLAGS.datasource == 'miniimagenet':
            self.loss_func = xent
```

See pages 6 and 7:

> "A significant computational expense in MAML comes.from the use of second derivatives when backpropagating the meta-gradient through the gradient operator in the meta-objective (see Equation (1)). On MiniImagenet, we show a comparison to a first-order approximation of MAML, where these second derivatives are omitted. Note that the resulting method still computes the meta-gradient
> at the post-update parameter values $θ^
> 0_i$, which provides for effective meta-learning. Surprisingly however, the performance of this method is nearly the same as that obtained with full second derivatives, suggesting that most of the
> improvement in MAML comes from the gradients of the objective at the post-update parameter values, rather than the second order updates from differentiating through the gradient update.".
> $$\theta \leftarrow \theta \; - \beta \nabla_\theta \sum_{\mathcal{T}_i\thicksim p (\mathcal{T})} \mathcal{L_{T_i}}(\mathcal{f}_{\theta^{{'}}_i}) \tag{1}
> $$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, unfortunately, I am not sure that I understand. In the code, you have sent me I can see that loss for each set of parameters in the inner gradient is passed to the outer loop however I still don't understand how it is backpropagated to the original $\theta$ . Derivations are handled by TensorFlow (I guess that it uses some clever tricks to avoid the Hessian) but I don't understand the principle...

Comment: @GrumpyC, that is described separately for omniglot and miniimagenet on pages 6&7 of the paper you cited; using a first-order approximation.

Comment: A different paper than the one you mentioned: "[ES-MAML: Simple Hessian-Free Meta Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.01215)" is clearer, backpropagation isn't used.

Comment: The term back-propagation is often misunderstood as meaning the whole learning algorithm for multi-layer neural networks. Actually, back-propagation refers only to **one** method for computing the gradient, while another algorithm, such as stochastic gradient descent, is used to perform learning using this gradient.

— Page 204, Deep Learning, 2016.

It would be fair to say that a neural network is trained or learns using Stochastic Gradient Descent as a shorthand, as it is assumed that the back-propagation algorithm is used to calculate gradients as part of the optimization procedure.

Comment: For a simplified explanation of the activation function see here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/choose-an-activation-function-for-deep-learning/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function